# Is there an efficient method of checking whether a column has mixed dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, typechecking

Consider

```
np.random.seed(0)
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 'a', 'b', [1, 2, 3]])
s2 = np.random.randn(len(s1))
s3 = np.random.choice(list('abcd'), len(s1))


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': s1, 'B': s2, 'C': s3})
df
           A         B  C
0          1  1.764052  a
1          2  0.400157  d
2          a  0.978738  c
3          b  2.240893  a
4  [1, 2, 3]  1.867558  a
```

Column "A" has mixed data types. I would like to come up with a really quick way of determining this. It would not be as simple as checking whether `type == object`, because that would identify "C" as a false positive.

I can think of doing this with

```
df.applymap(type).nunique() > 1

A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

But calling `type` atop `applymap` is pretty slow. Especially for larger frames.

```
%timeit df.applymap(type).nunique() > 1
3.95 ms ± 88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Can we do better (perhaps with NumPy)? I can accept "No" if your argument is convincing enough. :-)

Comment: Dont think a column could have different data type. I mean he could but  but that would be on the row .  The column itself would have only one data type. You could check it using df.info()

Comment: You would need to loop on all entries and check the type of the entry itself. If the set of entry type is bigger than 1, then you have mixed types. Just like you did.

Comment: Your difficulty is because pandas prefers to use object dtype instead a numpy string dtype.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: An early Xmas present? Thanks man, I'm chuffed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses the fact that in Python3 different types cannot be compared. The idea is to run `max` over the array which being a builtin should be reasonably fast. And it does short-cicuit.

```
def ismixed(a):
    try:
        max(a)
        return False
    except TypeError as e: # we take this to imply mixed type
        msg, fst, and_, snd = str(e).rsplit(' ', 3)
        assert msg=="'>' not supported between instances of"
        assert and_=="and"
        assert fst!=snd
        return True
    except ValueError as e: # catch empty arrays
        assert str(e)=="max() arg is an empty sequence"
        return False
```

It doesn't catch mixed numeric types, though. Also, objects that just do not support comparison may trip this up.

But it's reasonably fast. If we strip away all `pandas` overhead:

```
v = df.values

list(map(is_mixed, v.T))
# [True, False, False]
timeit(lambda: list(map(ismixed, v.T)), number=1000)
# 0.008936170022934675
```

For comparison

```
timeit(lambda: list(map(infer_dtype, v.T)), number=1000)
# 0.02499613002873957
```

Comment: This is not a python2 compatible solution which is a bummer, but I still like what you've done here! How would this scale for a DataFrame of size len(df) * 10000? (I would test it myself but I'm not at my workstation.)

Comment: @coldspeed Depends. As it short-circuits it should detect a mixed column pretty fast unless that column starts with a million same type elements and then has one outlier. On non-mixed arrays it does not so well. For example, for `np.ones(1000000, "O")` I'm getting 40 ms which is 6 times slower than the `infer_dtype` based solution.

Comment: @coldspeed Damn! I just found a bug. It will happily classify `np.array([np.inf, 'a']) as non-mixed, because after seeing `inf` it short-circuits. Too clever by half this Python beast.

Comment: Ah, damn! I would imagine you could mask the array using np.valid (if I got the name right) before doing this, but that's an additional layer of complexity. Let's see if it's worth it. May not be if the DataFrame actually has mixed types, in which case that'd just slow things down to the point where it isn't worth thinking about. Appreciate the effort though! This is almost perfect.

Comment: @coldspeed Turns out the bug isn't a bug. What happened is that `np.array([np.inf, 'a'])` evaluates to `array(['inf', 'a'], dtype='<U32')`. So I completely misread that. There appears to be no short-circuiting on object arrays.

Comment: I tried this (python3) on a dataframe containing numpy arrays within its cells (same type and shape within a column); the `max` operation fails because max isn't defined for this type.

Answer (score 21):

In pandas there's [`infer_dtype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.api.types.infer_dtype.html) which might be helpful here.

Written in Cython ([code link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/91802fb0accde031c3b6aca040a8b533a193fef6/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1081-L1318)), it returns a string summarising the values in the passed object. It's used a lot in pandas' internals so we might reasonably expect that's it has been designed with efficiency in mind.

```
>>> from pandas.api.types import infer_dtype
```

Now, column A is a mix of integers and some other types:

```
>>> infer_dtype(df.A)
'mixed-integer'
```

Column B's values are all of floating type:

```
>>> infer_dtype(df.B)
'floating'
```

Column C contains strings:

```
>>> infer_dtype(df.B)
'string'
```

The general "catchall" type for mixed values is simply "mixed":

```
>>> infer_dtype(['a string', pd.Timedelta(10)])
'mixed'
```

A mix of floats and integers is ''mixed-integer-float'':

```
>>> infer_dtype([3.141, 99])
'mixed-integer-float'
```

To make the function you describe in your question, one approach could be to create a function which catches the relevant mixed cases:

```
def is_mixed(col):
    return infer_dtype(col) in ['mixed', 'mixed-integer']
```

Then you have:

```
>>> df.apply(is_mixed)
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: 'mixed' in infer_dtype(x))` This is exactly what I needed. It's still a tad slow, but fast enough to make it worth the trouble. Thank you so much!

Comment: This looks like a clean approach, unfortunately it fails if you add a fourth column with only containers `s4 = pd.Series([[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5]])`, will give `True` for mixed types check.

Comment: @Darkonaut: that's true - it just defaults to 'mixed'. Might be worth raising an issue with the pandas devs if there's a more useful/usable return value to be had (perhaps something like 'container').

Comment: I think it's just with any Python object which is not a primitive. It's the same with `object()` for example. I don't see how pandas would have a chance infering the type for instances of custom classes. I'm not familiar with pandas' internals, though.

Comment: @Darkonaut I don't know how common it is to fill a `pd.Series` with instances of custom classes (or even standard containers) or even if it's recommended but maybe `infer_dtype` could return `container` for all standard containers in python and `custom_class` for the custom classes? Not perfect but better than just returning 'mixed' imo.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you need the result, but you can `map` the `type` to `df.values.ravel()` and create a dictionary of the name of the column link to the comparison of the `len` of a `set` superior to 1 for each slice of the `l` such as:

```
l = list(map(type, df.values.ravel()))
print ({df.columns[i]:len(set(l[i::df.shape[1]])) > 1 for i in range(df.shape[1])})
{'A': True, 'B': False, 'C': False}
```

Timing:

```
%timeit df.applymap(type).nunique() > 1
#3.25 ms ± 516 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit 
l = list(map(type, df.values.ravel()))
{df.columns[i]:len(set(l[i::df.shape[1]])) > 1 for i in range(df.shape[1])}
#100 µs ± 5.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

EDIT for larger dataframe, the improve in time is less interesting though:

```
dfl = pd.concat([df]*100000,ignore_index=True)

%timeit dfl.applymap(type).nunique() > 1
#519 ms ± 61.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
l = list(map(type, dfl.values.ravel()))
{dfl.columns[i]:len(set(l[i::dfl.shape[1]])) > 1 for i in range(dfl.shape[1])}
#254 ms ± 33.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

A bit faster solution on the same idea:

```
%timeit { col: len(set(map(type, dfl[col])))>1 for col in dfl.columns}
#124 ms ± 15.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but the speedup is not substantial enough to be meaningful for my purpose. I'll wait a bit longer to see if anything else comes up. Thanks for the answer.